# Отложенные сообщения в Telegram (Python Aiogram)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать отложенную отправку сообщения в Telegram боте через Python-библиотеку Aiogram?

К примеру, отправить сообщение 30.12.2020 в 12:00.